Is there any short key to bring view to 3D cursor?, Like the dot (.) for selected object viewing
If we far away from origin and set origin to world center how to get there quickly?

Press the Home key?

There are different possible ways of doing it, depending on what you want to do:

If you press the Home button, this would center the view onto the world's origin and frame all, i.e. zoom out as far as needed so that all objects are visible in the viewport - no matter where the 3D cursor is (even if it would be outside the viewport then).
If you press Shift+C this would also center the view on the world's origin and frame all, but also reset the 3D cursor to the world origin (0, 0, 0).
From the View menu, you can choose Align View > Center View to Cursor. This will center the view on the 3D cursor as the name says, no matter where it is in the world and without framing all in the scene. This menu option does not have a shortcut, but you can always create a custom one by right-clicking on it and choosing Assign Shortcut, or you chooose Add to Quick Favorites which makes it available in the Quick Favorites menu that you bring up with the shortcut Q.
Another way to snap the 3D cursor to the world origin but without changing the view is Shift+S and choosing Cursor to World Origin.
And a manual way to bring the 3D cursor to the world origin without changing the view would be to bring up the sidepanel with N, then go to the View tab and set the 3D Cursor > Location to (0, 0, 0).

Okay, the last ones were not really what you asked for - neither shortcuts nor centering on the world origin - I just thought I add them for completeness.

Thank you so much for this detailed post

In older Blender versions (i.e. 2.79), Alt + Home was the shortcut for that. However, in newer versions, a shortcut for this function was removed.
You can, however, assign your own shortcut:

by opening up the F3 menu, searching for "Center View to Cursor", right clicking on the provided function, and changing the shortcut to whatever works for you.

Which version of Blender is that? In my versions 3.6.9, 4.0.2, 4.1.1 and 4.2 the shortcut Alt+Home does nothing, not in Object Mode and not in Edit Mode either.

Ah, of course, sorry. I forgot that I'm still using parts of the old 2.79 keymap. Alt+Home was probably still available there, but was deprecated in 2.8 or following updates. I'll update my answer appropiately.

Sure, if there is something I forgot in my answer...

Thank you so much
